# How use Dynamic hyperlink on each wordpress post?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

I have designed a static design and button  on singlepost.php file now i want that when i create a new post then i want to put a hyperlink behind that button from post editor section. how can i do that ?

how i set hyperlink behind that "Get Deal" button from post page ?

Get Deal button is static for all post but this button take link when i put from post editor section (so there will be separate dynamic link for each post)

My static design code for post is :

```
<div class="price_row_grid">
    <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
        <?php theme_create_btn('no', 'price'); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="floatright vendor_for_grid">
        <?php if ($price_meta == 'admin'): ?>
            <?php $author_id = $post->post_author; ?>
            <a class="admin" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>">
                <?php echo get_avatar($author_id, '22'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php elseif ($price_meta == 'store'): ?>
            <div class="brand_logo_small">
                <?php WPSM_Postfilters::re_show_brand_tax('logo'); //show brand logo?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="price_row_grid">
        <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
            <p class="button">Get Deal</p>



        </div>
```

Now how i set hyperlink behind "Get Deal" from post editor because i just build button which is static for all pages but i want to set different hyperlink for each page.

Comment: Hi tony, do you mean you want to redirect your users to a new page after clicking that button?

Comment: Hi jack yes i want to redirect them but i just edited question please see the edits.

Comment: So you want to set the link yourself while you are publishing a post in admin panel? sorry your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Let me clear 
I built a static button from backend but i want that button get hyperlink from post editor

Comment: Yes i understand. But what would that link be? The link to post?To page? A link you type manually from the post editor?That's the important part.

Comment: Jack , That link redirect link but it should be open in new tab. There will be new redirect link for each page but button is static defined in backed.How i set link ?

Comment: If you just want to have a link you can use `<a href="STATIC URL HERE" target="_blank">Get Deal</a>` ...

Comment: Jack that's the problem i don't want static url. Each post have different url. But button is static.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a custom metabox on post edit screen, here's a good [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) on how to do that.


The tutorial will allow you to have another field on your Post Edit Screen called  '**Get Deals**'


After you follow that tutorial, replace

- 'smashing_post_class' **with** 'get_deals_link'
- 'Post Class' **with** 'Get Deals'
- 'Add a custom CSS class, which will be applied to WordPress' post class.' **with** 'Get Deals Link

then print your button something like this

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'get_deals_link', true );?>"
class="button">Get Deal</a>
```

I hope this helped you.